# In iPhone App How to Add an .edu Email verfication?

Tags: ios, swift, email, verification

I am trying to create a function that restricts sign up to strictly .edu sign up. How could I implement a function that would allow any University student to sign up as long as they have a .edu sign up. I have a Facebook registration function but after this, I want to redirect the users to an email confirmation screen.

```
func validate(email: String) -> Bool {
    do {             
        //instantiate a regex checking for valid email ending in .edu 
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\.edu$", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive) 
        //get the number of matches 
        let matches = regex.matches(in: email, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: email.characters.count)) 
        //if no matches, then email provided does not meet your requirements - otherwise the email validates 
        return matches.count > 0 
    } catch { //regular expression init failed... 
        return false 
    } 
}

//conform EmailConfirmationVC UITextFieldDelegate class EmailConfirmationVC: BaseTableVC, UITextFieldDelegate {

//set up your IBOutlets and other properties as you have already, avatar, nameValue, gener, etc -
@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set your email textfield delegate to self
    emailTF.delegate = self

    //the rest of your viewDidLoad...

}

//add the validate func above as a method of this class
func validate(email: String) -> Bool { //etc 
}

//then implement the textFieldDidEndEditing
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //for now, we are only interested in your email field - so if its not, return early
    if textField != emailTF { return }
    //else, safely unwrap and use the text from the field
    guard let userEmail = textField.text else { return }
    //then you the validate method to verify the email checks out
    let validEduEmail = validate(email: userEmail)

    if validEduEmail {
        //email is a valid .edu email -> move on to next registration steps, etc
    } else {
        //otherwise - this is not an .edu email - let the user know somehow
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you just want to make sure that when the signup button is tapped there is a text that ends in ".edu" in the email text field?

Comment: yeah and I want the user to confirm their email as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to check that it is a valid email ending in .edu, you could use a helper function like this:

```
    func validate(email: String) -> Bool {

        do {
            //instantiate a regex checking for valid email ending in .edu
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.edu$", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
            //get the number of matches
            let matches = regex.matches(in: email, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: email.characters.count))
            //if no matches, then email provided does not meet your requirements - otherwise the email validates
            return matches.count > 0
        } catch {
            //regular expression init failed... 
            return false
        }

    }
```

To then use this in the context of your viewcontroller above - you could do something like the following:

```
//conform EmailConfirmationVC UITextFieldDelegate
class EmailConfirmationVC: BaseTableVC, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //set up your IBOutlets and other properties as you have already, avatar, nameValue, gener, etc -
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTF: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set your email textfield delegate to self
        emailTF.delegate = self

        //the rest of your viewDidLoad...

    }

    //add the validate func above as a method of this class
    func validate(email: String) -> Bool { //etc 
    }

    //then implement the textFieldDidEndEditing
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //for now, we are only interested in your email field - so if its not, return early
        if textField != emailTF { return }
        //else, safely unwrap and use the text from the field
        guard let userEmail = textField.text else { return }
        //then you the validate method to verify the email checks out
        let validEduEmail = validate(email: userEmail)

        if validEduEmail {
            //email is a valid .edu email -> move on to next registration steps, etc
        } else {
            //otherwise - this is not an .edu email - let the user know somehow
        }

    }

}
```